# Is .NET DateTime thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is .NET DateTime thread safe? I'm not worried if the *read* operation returns incorrect value, my only concern is: will DateTime object get corrupted if not synchronized.

Comment: Are you only reading it from multiple threads? Or are you assigning to a `DateTime` field form multiple threads? The second is not safe.

Comment: Yes, I'm assigning to a DateTime from multiple threads. Will it throw an exception in such case? or will the only downside be that we cannot predict which thread's assignment operation executed the latest?

Comment: That is not safe.  The underlying value is a long, they are not atomic on a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: You can get a mix of two writes. The high 32 bit part of one write, and the low 32 bit part of another write. Operations on 64 bit values are not atomic on 32 bit systems.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: So you mean to say you could get a completely corrupted result from Date/Now/TimeStamp if accessed through a Thread?

Comment: @xfx `DateTime.Now` gives a valid result, since its contact guarantees that. It's not simply reading from a `DateTime` field.

Comment: So is it safe if running in 64 bit?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reads and writes to `DateTime` fields are not atomic (at least on 32 bit systems).

- If you assign from multiple threads to the same property at the same time you can corrupt it.
- If you read from one thread, and write from another, the reading thread might get corrupted values.
- Reading from multiple threads while having no writing threads at the same time is safe.

Essentially the two 32 bit halves of a `DateTime` might contain values of different age when used from multiple threads at the same time.

You can get a mix of two writes. The high 32 bit part of one write, and the low 32 bit part of another write.

As an alternative you can use an `Int64` for the field, and work on it with atomic methods from `Thread` and `Interlocked`. Then use `new DateTime(ticks)` and `dateTime.Ticks` to convert to/from `DateTime`.

MSDN says:

> All members of this type are thread safe. Members that appear to modify instance state actually return a new instance initialized with the new value. As with any other type, **reading and writing to a shared variable that contains an instance of this type must be protected by a lock to guarantee thread safety**.
>
> Assigning an instance of this type is not thread safe on all hardware platforms because the binary representation of that instance might be too large to assign in a single atomic operation.

Comment: But DateTime is immutable so its fields are never changed. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Robert In an immutable struct can't modify fields individually. But you can replace the content of a variable. It's this replacement operation essentially copies all fields. This replacement is not necessarily atomic. This differs from an immutable value type, where this replacement operation does not exist, since reassigning a variable only copies the reference, not the contents.

Comment: Instead of using Ticks, you may want to use DateTime.FromBinary(longValue) and dateTime.ToBinary(). The value will still fit in an Int64, and it will preserve the Kind property.

Comment: @CodesInChaos's earlier comment says `This differs from an immutable value type,` when it **should say** `This differs from an immutable REFERENCE type,`.

Comment: What if your value is a struct, such as DateTime, in a ConcurrentDictionary and you update a key's value?  What if it's in a normal Dictionary? Would a ConcurrentDictionary lock the value for the duration for the whole read/write of the KeyValuePair, ensuring it's read atomically?

Answer (score 13):

`DateTime` is an immutable value type (struct). You cannot change an instance once created.

It will not get corrupted and is thread safe.

If you are changing a `DateTime` *variable* from multiple threads (either writing or reading/writing), you need to synchronize - as this operation is **not** thread safe.