# Calling a Running thread c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows service, the Main thread spawns several child threads to perform work. The Main thread maintains a list of these threads by name. When a child completes, the Main thread removes it from the list. Main uses a timer to periodically start a child thread if it is not already running (by checking the list). The threads are started as "fire and forget" threads.
Sometimes a child thread can hang, or it may just be taking a very long time. But my Main thread has no way of knowing. I want the Main thread to be able to "call" a child thread and ask "are you doing something?" and if the child responds then i know he hasn't hung.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just leveraging the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) here?

Comment: What are your goals here? c# has many multithreading tools that can help you manage threads.

Comment: Each thread in C# have `ThreadState` property. Why don't you check if the state is `Running`?

Comment: @James probably for the same reason everyone insists on using sockets instead of higher-level constructs: not knowing they exist.

Comment: @James the code was written some time ago, and a rewrite isnt an option just now, although i have made a note to look at in future. Thanks.

Comment: @flapster no worries - when you say a thread can hang, what do you mean? That suggests to me a problem with your code running in the thread.

Comment: Would you be spinning new threads regularly? or only once child tasks are complete?

Comment: Avoid asking for an answer that you are not going to like.  Suppose you find out that a thread is hung, what are you going to do about it??  If your gut reaction is "I'll abort it!" then forget about it, that will not work.

Comment: @James, the thread can either be doing some FTP or SFTP, using some very old complicated code libraries and i havent yet been able to track down the problem when it hangs. So in the meantime, the workaround is to try and detect a hung thread and then restart the service once all the threads have finished. So i need to know that a thread is definitely hung, and not just transferring a very big file. Then i know which threads to wait for and which ones are hung. There are typically around 200 threads which get started every 2 minutes, unless already running (i.e. in the list).

Comment: @Hans - how do i avoid asking for an answer that i don't like, until i get the answer. Its a catch-22 !

Comment: Fix the bug, trying to put a bandaid on it won't stop the bleeding.

Comment: @flapster gotta agree with Hans here, it's pretty tricky to determine whether a thread is hung or whether it's just taking a bit longer to do something (although I am sure you will have your own thresholds that you deem acceptable waiting times). If it were me, I'd investigate the underlying problem whereby the thread *does* hang and what the cause of this is (and whether I could resolve it at that level and avoid choking the thread completely).

Comment: @james i agree, and i will eventually trace the cause of the hanging, but this code is legacy code from years ago written in old C, very complicated but on the whole it does work well. So really what i do need right now is a band-aid. Unfortunately this is needed 24x7 for business purposes, so we need to balance ideal solutions vs least cost solutions which in the end achieve the same result (as far as the business sees things). I'm going with Heinzi's solution, as we need a fix asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a *heartbeat*:

Every time some small action has been performed, the child thread updates a variable with the current UTC time. You will need one ([properly locked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14345164/87698)) variable for each thread (or a concurrent dictionary).

Your main thread regularly checks those heartbeats. If the heartbeat is older than some given amount of time, the main thread knows that some action of the child thread takes a lot longer than in should take.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My initial solution was something similar. I just wondered if there was some way of making a function call or other mechanism of inter-thread communication, but maybe with the model i currently have, yours is perhaps the best solution.