# C# - multiple thread start one thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 3 threads in 3 classes running in parallel. Each of them, increase `Pos` or `Neg` of the `Fourthclass` by "1". After 3 threads are done, if `Fourclass.Pos > Fourclass.Neg`, it will run `Terminal4`.

Q: How can i run the `Terminal4` only 1 time. Because putting `Fourthclass.Terminal4();` in each `Terminal1-2-3` will run the `Terminal4` 3 times.

Here is what i have done:

```
public class Firstclass
{
    static int Pos = 1;
    static int Neg = 0;
    public static void Terminal1()
    {
        if (Pos > Neg)
        {
            Fourthclass.Pos += 1;
         // Fourthclass.Terminal4();
        }
    }
}
public class Secondclass
{
    static int Pos = 1;
    static int Neg = 0;
    public static void Terminal2()
    {
        if (Pos > Neg)
        {
            Fourthclass.Pos += 1;
         // Fourthclass.Terminal4();
        } 
    }
}
public class Thirdclass
{
    static int Pos = 1;
    static int Neg = 0;
    public static void Terminal3()
    {
        if (Pos > Neg)
        {
            Fourthclass.Neg += 1;
         // Fourthclass.Terminal4();
        }
    }
}
public static class Fourthclass
{
    public static int Pos = 0;
    public static int Neg = 0;
    public static void Terminal4()
    {
        if (Pos > Neg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pos = {0} - Neg = {1}", Pos, Neg);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else { Console.WriteLine("fail"); }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread obj1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Firstclass.Terminal1));
        Thread obj2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Secondclass.Terminal2));
        Thread obj3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thirdclass.Terminal3));
        obj1.Start();
        obj2.Start();
        obj3.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static class Fourthclass { private static int count = 0; public static void Terminal4() { if(Interlocked.Increment(ref count) == 3) { /* Do something */ } } }`

Comment: @PetSerAl What can i do with this code? i don't understand how it work

Comment: You say `I have 3 threads in 3 classes running in parallel. Each of them, increase Pos or Neg of the Fourthclass by "1"`. I did not pick on it, but that is not the case in the code you show. Instead each class have a separate `Pos` and `Neg`. I think you should have a single class with all the `TerminalX` methods, so they share the same `Pos` and `Neg`.

Comment: @Theraot Each Classed will do different things, so there are some class running while the other are idle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### Original Answer

By the by... these increments are not thread safe, they may suffer the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) and that is ignoring thread visibility problems.

For that problem, please use [`Interloked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx). [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Interlocked.Decrement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y(v=vs.110).aspx) will take care of it.

Now, for making a code block run only once, keep an `int` variable that will be `1` if it did run, and `0` if it did not. Then use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int didrun;

// ...

if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref didrun, 1, 0) == 0)
{
    // code here will only run once, until you put didrun back to 0
}
```

There are other ways, of course. This one is just very versatile.

---

Addendum: Ok, what it does...

`Interlocked.CompareExchange` will look at the value of the passed variable (`didrun`) compare it to the second parameter (`0`) and if it matches, it will change the variable to the value of first parameter (`1`) [Since it may change the variable, you have to pass it by ref]. The return value is what it found in the variable.

Thus, if it returns `0`, you know it found `0`, which means that it did update the value to `1`. Now, the next time this piece of code is called, the value of the variable is `1`, so `Interlocked.CompareExchange` returns `1` and the thread does not enter the block.

Ok, **why do not use a `bool` instead?** Because of thread visibility. A thread may change the value of the variable, but this update could happen in CPU cache only, and not be visible to other threads... `Interlocked` gets around of that problem. Just use `Interlocked`. And [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/) is your friend.

---

That will work regardless if you are using `ThreadPool`, `Task` or `async/await` or just plain old `Threads` as you do. I mention that because I would like to suggest using those...

*Sneaky link to [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).*

---

### Extended Answer

In comment, you ask about a different behavior:

> The Terminal4 has cooldown until the next run

Well, if there is a cool down (which I understand as a period) you do not only need to store whatever or not the code did run, but also when was the last time it did.

Now, the conditional cannot be just "run only if it has not run yet" but instead "run if it has not run yet **or** if the period from the last time it ran to now is greater than the cool down".

We have to check multiple things, that is a problem. Now the check will no longer be atomic (from the Latin *atomus* which means indivisible, from *a-* "not" + *tomos* "a cutting, slice, volume, section").

That is relevant because if the check is not atomic, we are back to the ABA problem.

---

I will use this case to explain the ABA problem. If we encode the following:

```
1. Check if the operation has not run (if it has not go to 4)
2. Get the last time it ran
3. Compute the difference from the last run to now (exit if less than cool down)
4. Update the last run time to now
5. Run code
```

Two threads may do the following:

```
 |
 t  Thread1: Check if the operation has not run (it has)
 i  Thread2: Check if the operation has not run (it has)
 m  Thread2: Get the last time it ran
 e  Thread1: Get the last time it ran
 |  Thread1: Compute the difference from the last run to now (more than cool down)
 v  Thread2: Compute the difference from the last run to now (more than cool down)
    Thread2: Update the last run time to now
    Thread2: Run code
    Thread1: Update the last run time to now
    Thread1: Run code
```

As you see, they both `Run code`.

What we need is a way to check and update in a single `atomic` operation, that way the act of checking will alter the result of the other thread. That is what we get with `Interlocked`.

How `Interlocked` manages to do that is beyond the scope of the question. Suffice to say that there are some special CPU instructions for that.

---

The new pattern I suggest is the following (pseudocode):

```
bool canRun = false;
DateTime lastRunCopy;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if (try to set lastRun to now if lastRun is not set, copy lastRun to lastRunCopy)
{
    // We set lastRun
    canRun = true;
}
else
{
    if ((now - lastRunCopy) < cooldown)
    {
        if (try to set lastRun to now if lastRun = lastRunCopy, copy lastRun to lastRunCopy)
        {
            // we updated it
            canRun = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
            // Another thread got in
    }
}
if (canRun)
{
    // code here will only run once per cool down
}
```

Notice I have expressed the operations in terms of "try to set X to Y if X is Z, copy X to W" which is how `Interlocked.CompareExchange` works.

There is a reason I left that in pseudo code, and that is that [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) [is not an atomic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345164/is-net-datetime-thread-safe#14345231).

In order to make the code work we will have to use [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx). For an unset value we will use `0` (00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001), which is something you have to worry about for a cool down greater than a couple of millennia.

In addition, of course, we will use the overload of `Interlocked.CompareExchange` that takes `long` because `DateTime.Ticks` is of that type.

Note: Ah, we will use [`TimeSpan.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) for the cool down.

The code is as follows:

```
long lastRun = 0;
long cooldown = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks; // Or whatever, I do not know.

// ...

bool canRun = false;
long lastRunCopy = 0;
long now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
lastRunCopy = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastRun, now, 0);
if (lastRunCopy == 0)
{
    // We set lastRun
    canRun = true;
}
else
{
    if ((now - lastRunCopy) < cooldown)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastRun, now, lastRunCopy) == lastRunCopy)
        {
            // we updated it
            canRun = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Another thread got in
        }
    }
}
if (canRun)
{
    // code here will only run once per cooldown
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to boil it down to a single conditional:

```
long lastRun = 0;
long cooldown = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks; // Or whatever, I do not know.

// ...

long lastRunCopy;
var now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
if
(
    (lastRunCopy = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastRun, now, 0)) == 0
    || now - lastRunCopy < cooldown
    && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref lastRun, now, lastRunCopy) == lastRunCopy
)
{
    // code here will only run once per cooldown
}
```

As I said, `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is versatile. Although, as you can see, you still need to think around the requirements.

Comment: As my goal is: There will be many Threads will increase Pos&Neg in same and different times (the increment of Pos&Neg which provide to Terminal4 of Those Threads will be remove after an amount of time). The Terminal4 has cooldown until the next run. Although the Pos and Neg of Fourthclass keep increasing, but if "Terminal4" is in cooldown, it won't work. Is your solution suit for my future goal?

Comment: @Hifumi updated my answer to cover how to do a thread safe cool down.