# C# Item is null for very short period of time?

Tags: c#

I have a `MessageQueue` class with a private `List` property that acts as the queue. There's only one way to add to the queue (through an `Add` method) and one way to take from the queue (through a `Next` method). I have a thread running without a delay constantly checking the queue. Occasionally, a `null` item gets into the queue.

I put a breakpoint in the `Add` method if the item being added is null, but the breakpoint is never hit.

I put a breakpoint in the `Next` method if the item being returned is `null`, which is getting hit.

Furthermore, the breakpoint is set after it fetches the item, but before the queue is adjusted. What's strange is, while the returned item is `null`, the item that was *just fetched* is not null! Here is my queue-

```
public class MessageQueue
{
    private List<byte[]> queue = new List<byte[]>();

    public void Add(byte[] payload)
    {
        if (payload == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thats why");
        }

        queue.Add(payload);
    }

    public byte[] Next()
    {
        byte[] hand = queue.First();

        if(hand == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("asdf");
        }

        queue = queue.Skip(1).ToList();

        return hand;
    }

    public bool HasMessages
    {
        get
        {
            return queue.Count() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what's in the queue-

[image]

And here is what's in the hand-

[image]

Because I am using `First` on the queue, an error would be thrown if there wasn't an item.

In fact, just to be sure that wasn't somehow related I put a try-catch around the `First` call- which is never hit.

How is `hand` null when null is never added to the queue, and the first item in the queue is not null?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads by chance?

Comment: Also, a `Queue<T>` would make **much** more sense as a Queue than `List<T>`

Comment: @MitchWheat Well sure it does! `queue = queue.Skip(1).ToList();`. Not the most efficient removal I've ever seen, but still.

Comment: you may want to have a look at  ConcurrentQueue

Comment: @itsme86. It's such an inefficient way that I would never consider, I missed it!

Comment: `queue.Add(payload);` Is there a reason you call this even when `payload` is `null`?

Comment: You guys are scrutinizing this hack code way too much. @itsme86 I didn't start with `queue.Skip(1).ToList()`- I was trying something. @mjwills I check if payload is null so I could put a breakpoint on it. Thanks @Keith Nicholas- that was helpful

Comment: It's actually the `queue.Add(payload);` that's causing your data to *intermediately* hold `null` values (as seen from concurrent threads).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List<> [is not thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.90).aspx)

If you are accessing it from different thread you can see it in a broken state.
Use any [synchronization technique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-synchronization) or anything from [thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)

As mentioned above: "ConcurrentQueue is most likely what you need to use"

Comment: You should add that `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is most likely what the OP needs to use

Comment: `List<> is not thread safe` - Good to know. That's probably the cause of some of my other anomalies.

Comment: If you didn't know that, know that most things in .net are not thread-safe, even DateTime structure

Comment: @Evk Very common mistake. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_10 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345164/is-net-datetime-thread-safe

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy but that's another story. `DateTime` is still thread-safe, because immutable. But assignments and reads to variables\fields of `DateTime` type are not thread-safe. Though "thread-safe" is quite vague term, so I see what you mean.